# Date conversion failing on selected date

Tags: sql-server

Hi, I am wondering why this date: **11/4/2011** fails when I do a conversion.

E.g. `convert(date,date_field,103)` returns as expected but when the convert function is trying to convert this date **11/17/2011** it returns conversion failed.

I tried `ltrim` to see if there is white space but the same error is returning,
I also tried `isdate` to make sure it is a date and `isdate` is returning greater than 0.

I know this is basic but could someone give an insight as to why it is rejecting the date?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) says 103 = dd/mm/yyyy. Your date is "11/17/2011".

Is there a 17th month?

Comment: the date 11/17/2014 stands for november 17 2011 same with 11/04/2014 should i use another convertion code?

Comment: Look at the MSDN page I linked in my answer: there is a list of codes; find the one that matches the format you're using.

Answer (score 1):

use varchar instead of date. like below

```
Select Convert(Varchar,'11/17/2011',103)
```